# Uncaught TypeErrors using jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

First off, want to say a BIG thanks to this community. Always found answers here and now that I am using it I enjoy it! When I can give back as far as answers, I will! Thank you guys for the fastest, most efficient and most helpful community. Keep it up!

My issue today is a jQuery plugin I am trying to use, which takes a InstaGram feed and puts it on a website, when you click on one of the images it opens up in a lightbox.

However, it won't load and I am gettings two issues in the web inspector:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined instaviewr.js:1
>   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'simpleInstagramFancybox' /jqueryissue/:73

Here is the site: http://tempsmz.hostzi.com/jqueryissue/
Anything I am doing wrong?

Any details I can include I will happily do!

Comment: For some reason the $ shortcut to jQuery does not seem to be defined when loading http://tempsmz.hostzi.com/jqueryissue/files/instaviewr.js
Maybe this problem occurs because you include multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: btw. you are including jQuery three times: Version 1.4, 1.7.1 and 1.7.2